# how i can global a value in my drupal module?

Tags: php, function, drupal, drupal-7

I want to globalize a value in order to use this value in all my function in my code. Could you help me someone with that thing? i want the values $username and $password to use them in 4 different functions. I can do it just

```
global $username;
```

and

```
global $password;
```

in a random function??

Comment: It is not that good to use global variables! Why don't you simply give it to the functions as parameters?

Comment: I know I just want to know... Is this the way that i think?

Comment: First, there is drupalanswers.stackoverflow.com for Drupal related answers. Second, Drupal already provides a global `$user` variable. But of course, for security reasons, the password is not in the user object. It's salted and hashed anyway, so there is no way to obtain the actual password in Drupal.